# Excel power query slow

Tags: microsoft-excel, postgresql, power-query

I'm very new to Power Query and I have started trying to use it with our production database which is running a PostgreSQL server. For the record I am using Excel 2016 64-bit version with the pgqlODBC driver and when I try to load a table with ~16m records the preview table with simply spin ad infinitum.

Comment: Is it filling out the rows slowly? Or just slow to initiate in general?

Comment: The preview will never load, it's not really possible for me to work with any table with any decent amount of records because the spinner will just spin forever.

Comment: What makes you think you can load 16m records? Excel is limited to 1,048,576 rows ...

Comment: Well I don't want to work with 16M records directly but most RDBMS is intuitive enough to only load a slice of the data when displaying data from a large table.

Answer (score 0):

Power Query tries to "fold" your query steps into source system code eg PQ Filters become SQL WHERE clauses.  If there are no Filters it tries to do something like TOP (200).  This is obscure and internal, and doesn't always work even against mainstream databases.

I would add a Filter as early as possible in the query design, e.g. just a single transaction date.  Once the query is fully designed, it's easy and safe to go back and delete that Filter step.